# I found out that my PhD topic has been done before, what can I do , to make it an original topic without changing the main idea

Tags: phd

I am a PhD student , and I am in my first year, started four months ago

Comment: Talk to your supervisor.  There is always a way to study an idea/problem in a more in-depth manner.  It's also possible to ask a different question but this requires experience.

Comment: I asked an experienced PhD supervisor in the UK this myself and his response was "it's no problem, all different twigs on the branch".

Answer (score 4):

**Ask your advisor**. Your advisor:

- Is likely to be the person most familiar with the direction your thesis is supposed to take, and therefore able to advise on how to modify it
- Is likely to be much more experienced than you and therefore better-positioned to decide what to do next
- Is likely to care enough to provide you with that advice
- You can't do anything without your supervisor's approval anyway

It's possible you'll end up changing topics (since it's only been four months anyway), you might find that the previous work isn't exactly the same as yours, etc. But this is all speculation. Ask your advisor and figure it out from there.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the easier path is to work with your advisor to find a different problem, related or not. In some ways you are lucky to learn of this now, rather than in a year.

You haven't wasted four months, I hope, but rather have learned some things about research and about your field.

If the other work is recent then I would guess that there is other work going on on that topic, so that some minor change in direction or approach might also get scooped. Being in a hot field is pretty nice, but there is a lot of parallel work going on.

For other reasons it isn't unusual to take a while to find a suitable problem. I had that experience. I worked on one problem (math) that was so easy that I got theorems proved every day. Too easy, so no significance. Then I worked on a problem for a while for which no insight or advancement could be had. Too hard, so a long term investment at best. The third problem was the charm. Significant and do-able. But each problem taught me things, so the time and effort wasn't wasted.